# IronPDF FormField value with new line

Tags: ironpdf

Using IronPDF, I need to fill in a PDF Form Text Field with a multiline string.  A single string works fine, but using Environnment.NewLine adds a symbol; \n and \r\n are displayed as text.

I need to avoid modifying the PDF in any way.

```
'Example that isn't working
Dim pdf = PdfDocument.FromFile("mypdf.pdf")
pdf.Form.Fields(0).Value = "A string with" & Environment.NewLine & "multiple lines"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IronPDF support said this isn't possible yet, but is planned for a future release.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was applying the new line in the HTML:

```html
<div>
    @{
        var text = @Model.Value.Split("\n");
        foreach (string line in text)
        {
            @line.ToString();
            <br />
        }
    }
</div>
```